# Conversion from string "Date Booked" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, charts

I have a Chart in VB.NET and it doesn't load on the form when started.
The chart is supposed to display the price of the room on the y axis and date booked on the x axis.

Whenever the form is loaded, I get the error message in the title.

I am new to coding and this is the code my friend has used but it works in their project.

The problem seems to lie with the database but I've created a new database and still received this error.

```vb
    Private Sub frmSalesAndRevenue_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Populate DGV

        DB.ExecQuery("SELECT BookingID, RoomType, Revenue, DateBooked FROM tblRoomBookings ORDER BY BookingID ASC")
        LoadGrid()

        Try
            DBCon.Open()
            Dim QRY As String
            QRY = "SELECT BookingID, RoomType, Revenue, DateBooked FROM tblRoomBookings ORDER BY BookingID ASC"
            DBCmd = New OleDbCommand(QRY, DBCon)
            READ = DBCmd.ExecuteReader

            While READ.Read
                chtSalesAndRevenue.Series("Revenue").Points.AddXY(READ.GetString("DateBooked"), READ.GetInt32("Price"))
            End While
            DBCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        PlotChart()
    End Sub
```

```vb
    Private Sub PlotChart()
        Dim TA As New NewHotelDataSetTableAdapters.tblRoomBookingsTableAdapter
        Dim TB = TA.GetData()

        chtSalesAndRevenue.Series(0).Points.Clear()

        For i = -364 To 0
            Dim revenueOfDay As Single = 0

            For H As Integer = 0 To TB.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim T As NewHotelDataSet.tblRoomBookingsRow = TB.Rows(H)

                If T._Check_In = Now.Date.AddDays(i) Then
                    MsgBox("g")
                    revenueOfDay += T.Revenue
                End If
            Next

            Try
                chtSalesAndRevenue.Series(0).Points.AddXY(Now.Date.AddDays(i), revenueOfDay)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
```

I get this error message on the line "Dim TB = TA.GetData()": "System.Data.ConstraintException: 'Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.'"

[Screen print of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29r6i.png)

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: What is the datatype of the column DateBooked in your database table?

Comment: Also you use a _READ.GetInt32("Price")_ but there is no Price column in the select query

Comment: @Steve it is in ShortText format as when I try to make it a Date/Time it changes itself back. I delete the column and create a new one with Date/Time format and it changes back

Comment: @Steve That was supposed to be "Revenue" thank you, but it still comes up with the error

Comment: You say Access changes Date/Time to Text type in table design? Never seen that. Your friend's db has date/time field? Edit question to show sample data as text tables.

Comment: @June7 My friend used Date/Time format and I have added a screen print of the database to the post

Comment: All your date fields are displayed left-aligned, thus probably of data type _Text_, not _DateTime_. Change that, or you will face endless troubles.

Comment: To get a DateTime, you should be using `READ.GetDateTime("DateBooked")`. If it isn't a DateTime, then the database should be corrected.

Comment: Thank you @Gustav I have made your suggested change

Comment: Thank you @AndrewMorton I have made your suggested change